# Compare two arrays and concat without duplicates

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I have two arrays. I can push and splice by clicking on a word in searchWords, which adds or removes a word to the currentWordlist.

What I want to have is a button that transfers all the searchWords to the currentWordlist, without overwriting the words that are actually on the currentWordlist.

I came up with this code:

```
$scope.addAll = function () {
    var searchWords = [];
    var currentWords = [];

    // safes all searchwords to the array
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.searchWords.length; i++) {
      searchWords.push($scope.searchWords[i]);
    }

    // safes all currentwords to the array
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.currentWordlist.length; j++) {
      currentWords.push($scope.currentWordlist[j]);
    }

    console.log("searchWords " + searchWords.length);
    console.log("currentWords " + currentWords.length);

    angular.forEach(searchWords, function(value1, key1) {
      angular.forEach(currentWords, function(value2, key2) {
        if (value1._id !== value2._id) {
          $scope.currentWordlist.push(value1);
        }
      });
    });
  };
```

I go through both of the arrays and safe them so that I can use the arrays inside my two `angular.forEach` to check if there are duplicates. If I don't push to the currentWordlist. But it's not working. I get an `[ngRepeat:dupes]` error, but I cannot use track by $index because otherwise removing from the list removes the wrong word. I think I am doing something critically wrong here, but I couldn't find out what so far (hours of trial and error :0)

Comment: consider using indexOf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use angular `unique` filter with `ng-repeat` directive. The code could be as follows:

```
$scope.addAll = function () {
  // use angular.copy to create a new instance of searchWords
  $scope.combinedWords = angular.copy($scope.searchWords).concat($scope.currentWordlist);
};
```

And then in your view:

```
<div ng-repeat="word in combinedWords | unique:'_id'">
  {{word}}
</div>
```

Usage:

```
colection | uniq: 'property'
```

It also possible to filter by nested properties:

```
colection | uniq: 'property.nested_property'
```

Comment: This really does the trick, nice and smooth. Thank you very much for the information about the filter!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do like this

```
    angular.forEach($scope.searchWords, function(value1, key1) {
      var temp=true;
      angular.forEach($scope.currentWordlist, function(value2, key2) {
        if (value1.id === value2.id)
          temp=false;
      });
      if(temp)
        $scope.currentWordlist.push(value1);
    });
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  
  $scope.searchWords=[{id:1,name:'A'},{id:2,name:'B'},{id:1,name:'A'},{id:4,name:'D'}];
  $scope.currentWordlist=[];
  $scope.addAll = function() {
    
    angular.forEach($scope.searchWords, function(value1, key1) {
      var temp=true;
      angular.forEach($scope.currentWordlist, function(value2, key2) {
        if (value1.id === value2.id)
          temp=false;
      });
      if(temp)
        $scope.currentWordlist.push(value1);
    });
    
    console.log($scope.currentWordlist);
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <button ng-click="addAll(newWord)">Add</button>
  <div>{{currentWordlist}}</div>
</div>
```